# Array to string conversion - Laravel 5.6 Error

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update values in the DB using values from a JSON file:

Code:

```
$jsonData = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
        $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

        //check if hospital exist
        $name = explode(' ',trim($data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['name']));
        // echo $name[0];
        $query = Hospital::where('h_name',  'LIKE' , '%' . $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['name'] . '%')->first();

        if($query){

            // echo "\n yupo";
            $h_id = $query->id;
            $h_slug = $query->h_slug;
            $nr_orgUnit = $query->nr_orgUnit;

            // echo $nr_orgUnit;
            $updateHospital = Hospital::find($h_id);
            $updateHospital->h_name = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["name"];
            $updateHospital->h_short_name = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["shortName"];
            $updateHospital->h_code = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["code"];
            $updateHospital->h_opening_date = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["openingDate"];
            $updateHospital->h_closed_date = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["closedDate"];
            $updateHospital->h_active = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["active"];
            $updateHospital->h_comment = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["comment"];
            $updateHospital->h_geo_code = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["geoCode"];
            $updateHospital->h_last_updated = $data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["lastUpdated"];
            $updateHospital->save();
} else {
            // echo 'error';
        }
```

JSON DATA:

```
 {"organisationUnits":{
  "organisationUnit":{
     "id":"01",
     "uuid":{

     },
     "name":"Isagehe Dispensary",
     "shortName":"Isagehe Dispensary ",
     "code":"17-04-0118",
     "openingDate":"1990-01-01",
     "closedDate":{

     },
     "active":"true",
     "comment":{

     },
     "geoCode":{

     },
     "lastUpdated":{

     }
  }
}
}
```

when i try to run the code, i get the following error:

> Array to string conversion (SQL: update `ag_hospitals` set `h_closed_date` = , `h_active` = true, `h_comment` = , `h_geo_code` = , `h_last_updated` =  where `id` = 41)"

where might i be wrong?

Note i have also tried updating the following way:

```
$updateHospital = Hospital::where('id', $h_id)->update([
                                'h_name' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['name'], 
                                'h_short_name' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['shortName'], 
                                'h_code' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['code'], 
                                'h_opening_date' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['openingDate'], 
                                'h_closed_date' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['closedDate'], 
                                'h_active' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['active'], 
                                'h_comment' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['comment'], 
                                'h_geo_code' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['geoCode'], 
                                'h_last_updated' => $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['lastUpdated']
                            ]);
```

Comment: Wheter the `$data["organisationUnits"]["organisationUnit"]["closedDate"]` is the string? Try check it.

Comment: `$data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['comment']` and `$data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['geoCode']` are empty objects, not strings. You may want to check to see if those values are empty and write an empty string or null instead of the value.

Comment: i have set them to NULL and it worked, how can i convert the objects to strings on `$data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['comment']` and `$data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['geoCode']`?

Comment: For empty objects, just use `empty($data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['comment']) ? '' : $data['organisationUnits']['organisationUnit']['comment']`. You may want to double-check the structure when there is data to find out if it's a string, object, or an array, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that Attribute in Model that store that JSON Data as Array.
Example:

```
protected $casts = [
        'column_name' => 'array'
    ];
```